# Approximation of one function by other using a smooth multiplier function

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

This problem is from the Book, Harmonic Analysis by Katznelson (Problem 2, Page 160).

Suppose $f$, $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x) = 0$ implies $g(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then show that for $\epsilon >0$, there exists a twice differentiable compactly supported $\phi$ such that $\|\phi f - g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}< \epsilon$.

Hints and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Notation:** the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function
>   $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as
>   $$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-2\pi i\xi y}dy,\quad\xi\in\mathbb{R}$$ and the Fourier transform on $L^{2}$ is the
>   unique extension of this operator. The inverse Fourier transform is
>   analogously defined and denoted by $f^{\vee}$ We use the notation
>   $\tau^{y}$, where $h\in\mathbb{R}$, to define a translation operator
>   $(\tau^{y}g)(x)=g(x-y)$. We denote the Lebsgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$
>   by $\left|\cdot\right|$.

---

Let $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, and let $E:=\text{supp}(\widehat{f})=\left\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}:\widehat{f}(\xi)=0\right\}$. Here, we are choosing $f$ to be a representative element of its $L^{2}$ equivalence class or considering the equivalence class of $E$ modulo null sets. Consider the subset $H\subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by

$$H:=\left\{g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) : \widehat{g}(\xi)=0, \quad \text{a.e. }\xi \in E\right\} \tag{1}$$

> **Lemma** $H$ is a closed, translation-invariant linear subspace
>   of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

*Proof:* It is evident from the linearity of the Fourier transform that $H$ is a subspace. To see that $H$ is closed, suppose that a sequence $g_{n}\in H$ converges to some $g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. By the continuity of the Fourier transform, $\widehat{g}_{n}\rightarrow\widehat{g}$ in $L^{2}$; passing to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $\widehat{g}_{n}\rightarrow\widehat{g}$ almost everywhere (a.e.). As $\widehat{g}_{n}(\xi)=0$ for a.e. $\xi\in E$, it follows from disregarding a countable union of null sets that $\widehat{g}(\xi)=0$ for a.e. $\xi\in E$. To see that $H$ is translation-invariant, we recall the basic property of the Fourier transform that $\widehat{\tau^{h}g}=e^{-2\pi i h\cdot}\widehat{g}$. $\Box$

Since $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a (separable) Hilbert space, $H$ is a Hilbert space. I claim that $H=\overline{\text{span}}\left\{\tau^{y}f : y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. It suffices to show that if $g\in H$ satisfies $\langle{g,\tau^{y}f}\rangle=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $g=0$ a.e. By Plancherel's theorem,

$$0=\langle{g,\tau^{h}f}\rangle=\langle{\widehat{g},\widehat{\tau^{h}f}}\rangle=\langle{\widehat{g},e^{-2\pi iy\cdot}\widehat{f}}\rangle=\left(\widehat{g}\overline{\widehat{f}}\right)^{\vee},\tag{2}$$

where in the last equality we use the fact that $\widehat{g}\overline{\widehat{f}}\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and therefore has a Fourier transform given by a  $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ function. By Fourier inversion, we obtain that $\widehat{g}\overline{\widehat{f}}=0$ a.e. As $\widehat{f}\neq 0$ a.e. on $E^{c}$, we must have that $\widehat{g}\neq 0$ a.e. on $E^{c}$. Whence, $\widehat{g}=0$ a.e. and by Parseval's theorem, $g=0$ a.e.

Now given $\epsilon>0$ and $g\in H$, the preceding result gives us a finite linear combination of translates of $f$, $f_{\epsilon}:=a_{1}\tau^{y_{1}}f+\cdots+a_{m}\tau^{y_{m}}f$, such that

$$\epsilon>\left\|g-f_{\epsilon}\right\|_{L^{2}}=\left\|\widehat{g}-\widehat{f}_{\epsilon}\right\|_{L^{2}}=\left\|\widehat{g}-\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\cdot }\widehat{f}\right\|_{L^{2}} \tag{3}$$

It is evident that $\sum_{j}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\cdot}$ defines a $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$ function. Let $N>0$ be sufficiently large so that

$$\int_{\left|\xi\right|\geq N}\left|\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\xi}\widehat{f}(\xi)\right|^{2}d\xi<\epsilon^{2}\tag{4}$$

Let $\varphi\in C_{c}^{\infty}$ be a smooth, compactly suppoted function which is $0\leq\varphi\leq 1$, $1$ on $[-N,N]$, and $0$ outside $(-2N,2N)$. Define a $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ function $\Phi$ by

$$\Phi(\xi):=\varphi(\xi)\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\xi}, \quad\xi\in\mathbb{R} \tag{5}$$

Observe that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\left[\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\xi}-\Phi(\xi)\right]\widehat{f}(\xi)\right|^{2}d\xi\leq\int_{N\leq\left|\xi\right|}\left|1-\varphi(\xi)\right|^{2}\left|\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\xi}\right|^{2}\left|\widehat{f}(\xi)\right|^{2}d\xi$$

To estimate the right-hand side (RHS), we note that $\left|1-\varphi\right|^{2}$, whence the RHS is $\leq$
$$\int_{\left|\xi\right|\geq N}\left|\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\xi}\right|^{2}\left|\widehat{f}(\xi)\right|^{2}d\xi<\epsilon^{2} \tag{6}$$

Using this estimate with (3), we conclude from the triangle inequality that

$$\left\|\widehat{g}-\Phi\widehat{f}\right\|_{L^{2}}\leq\left\|\widehat{g}-\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\cdot}\widehat{f}\right\|_{L^{2}}+\left\|\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}e^{-2\pi i y_{j}\cdot}\widehat{f}-\Phi\widehat{f}\right\|_{L^{2}}<2\epsilon \tag{7}$$

Comment: the answer is okay, but if you will see the book, you will find you have done way around. Katznelson wants to conclude the description of closed translation invariant subspaces of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ using this problem. And what you have done is first found the description of closed translation invariant and then use that to conclude the problem. So if u can solve it without using the description of closed translation invariant subspaces of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, your solution will be much appreciated. Please see the problem following this problem in the book, and u will get my point.

Comment: Link of the Book(see page 160):
http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~picard/SMC/didattica/materiali_did/Anal.Armon./Katznelson/Katznelson.pdf

Comment: @RakeshBalhara: You can strip out the part about translation invariance and directly show that the subspace of $H$ generated by the functions $e^{-2\pi i y\cdot}\widehat{f}$ is dense in $H$. Then proceed to the last part of the proof to get your function $\Phi$.

Comment: Again that is just rephrasing the words, I am pretty sure there must be some other way of proving it.. Anyways thanks for the solution. At least you deserve my hardly earned 50 points :)